# How to replace these strings via regex?

Tags: c#, regex, string, windows-phone-7

I work on a project target on Windows Phone 7.5 and above.

**What I Want**
make strA to strB,
strA has bunch of [img]attachmenti[/img] pair, and I want convert the [img] pair to another pair which I can use it in a RichTextBox.[I have an array which holds the image's url and I will pass it to the Image Source property]

```
//example data
strA = this a good day.[img]attachment1[/img]I love it[img]attachment2[/img];
strB = this a good day.<InlineUIContainer><Image Source="XXXXXX"></Image><InlineUIContainer>I love it<InlineUIContainer><Image Source="XXXXXX"></Image><InlineUIContainer>
```

**What's the problem**
I use MatchCollection to get all the match corresponding parts in the string. I check the result in the immediate window, the code is OK, but the problem is MatchCollection is readonly, I can not replace its value, so how can I replace these strings after matching or is there a better way to implement this?

```
                foreach (var item in rawdata.data) 
                {
                    if ( item.thumbnail != null)  
                    { 
                         MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(item.text, @"\[img\](.+?)\[/img\]", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Singleline);
                         int i = 0;
                         foreach (Match nextMatch in mc) 
                         {
                             string imghead = @"<InlineUIContainer><Image" + " Source=\"" + item.thumbnail[i] + "\">";

                             StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                             sb.Append(@"<InlineUIContainer><Image");
                             sb.Append(" Source=\"");
                             sb.Append(item.thumbnail[i]);
                             sb.Append("\">");
                             sb.Append(@"</Image></InlineUIContainer>");

                             nextMatch.Value.Replace( nextMatch.Value, sb.ToString());

                             i = i + 1;
                         }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: There should be a replace function where you can supply a callback function to do the replacement. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht1sxswy.aspx

Comment: `nextMatch.Value.Replace` doesn't modify the original string. Search SO for `Regex.Replace`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string str = Regex.Replace(item.text, @"\[img\](.+?)\[/img\]", @"<InlineUIContainer><Image Srouce=\"$1\" /></InlineUIContainer>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```